# Celery scheduling right way

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have a question about the correct use of celery. Now I have a project in which there is an entity Сompany that has an API_token of one service from which I will take data to my database, the user can add, change or delete this token. There can be > 1000 companies. How to schedule updating of data from this service correctly.

Now I see 2 ways:

1. Create one schedule that would run tasks for all companies
2. Create schedule for every company
   Are both methods good or is one of the approaches better or are they all wrong?
   I will be glad of any answers and criticism

Example of one method:

```
@shared_task()
def update_wb_statistic(company: Company) -> None:
    if company.wbToken:
        company_api = WildberriesAPI(company)
        company_api.get_incomes()
        company_api.get_sales()
        company_api.get_stocks()
        company.wbLastUpdate = datetime.now()


@shared_task()
def update_companies():
    companies = Company.query.all()
    for company in companies:
        if company.wbToken:
            update_wb_statistic.delay(company)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better approach depends on the configuration of workers, resource limitation and use case(real time/background scheduling). Pros:

**Creating multiple tasks**

- Flexible and Scalable. Can be run concurrently on multiple workers running on single or multiple noes. Huge time saving for time taking functions
- Incase of retry of any exceptions, single company entity is reprocessed instead of all. If you expect exceptions frequently and want to retry, follow this configuration

**Creating single task**

- Less complexity and easier to debug.
- More suited for background jobs where time isn't a constraint.